# Remove attitributes not apart of an array MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

Due to some poorly planned code earlier on, my server added a lot of redundant attributes to log documents pushed to MongoDB. I'd like to roll through the entire database and $unset attributes that do not fit an approved list.

So basically, if a document looks like this:

```
{
_id: ...,
content: ...,
attr_sub: ...,
attr_sub_0_attr_sub: ...,
...
}
```

I want to match it with ["_id", "content", "attr_sub"], thus unsetting other attributes, and giving me:

```
{
_id: ...,
content: ...,
attr_sub: ...
}
```

For the life of me, I can't think of a way to do this, please tell me this is possible with mongodb conditions...

Comment: How do you plan to pass in ["_id", "content", "attr_sub"]? Mykola's approach seems doable if the query matches what you want. Though a simple `$unset` will do.

Answer (score 0):

How about findOneAndReplace method?

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOneAndReplace

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/

Here is simple code that will modify your documents

```
var coll = db.collection("yourCollection");
var cursor = coll.find({"_id", "content"});
cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    var goodDoc = {
        content : doc.content,
        attr_sub : doc.attr_sub
    };
    coll.findOneAndReplace({_id: doc._id}, goodDoc, function(err){
        console.log("Updated: " + doc._id);
    })
}, function(err) {
    console.log("Cursor done send commands. Commands still running");
});
```

Hope this helps.